# python/ast: evaluate an ast.Subscript node

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm using ast to parse python files and I can't work out how to get an ast.Subscript node to evaluate. I can't even see how to get the text out of it (so I could use eval(text) ). Can anyone see what I'm missing?

For example, here the default value for the A arg is an expression which I want to evaluate. Ast returns the default value as an ast.Subscript node. How can I evaluate that?

```
import ast
import os

text = """
def test(A=os.environ["USER"][0]):
    return A
"""

fnDef = ast.parse(text).body[0]
argDefault = fnDef.args.defaults[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `ast.dump(node)`, you can see what your node is composed of. In your case (indentation is mine):

```
print(ast.dump(fnDef))
> FunctionDef(name='test', 
        args=arguments(
            args=[arg(arg='A', annotation=None)], 
            vararg=None, 
            varargannotation=None, 
            kwonlyargs=[], 
            kwarg=None, 
            kwargannotation=None, 
            defaults=[
                Subscript(
                    value=Subscript(
                        value=Attribute(
                            value=Name(id='os', ctx=Load()),
                            attr='environ', ctx=Load()),
                        slice=Index(value=Str(s='USER')), 
                        ctx=Load()), 
                    slice=Index(value=Num(n=0)), 
                    ctx=Load())], 
            kw_defaults=[]), 
        body=[Return(value=Name(id='A', ctx=Load()))], 
        decorator_list=[], 
        returns=None)
```

As you can see, your Subscript nodes are composed of a value, a slice and a ctx. The first slice (`["USER"]`) is an Index which value is a Str node, the second (`[0]`) slice is an Index which value is a Num node.

You can also see that in the [abstract grammar](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ast.html#abstract-grammar) (see 
the 'slice' type).